# how to convert xml to json in wso2

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

**Scenario**
I've implemented an API which makes a soap call to external service. I need to convert the response from xml to json (which is actually happening). But somehow I'm unable to convert the nested xml nodes to json.

**API**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api context="/nadra" name="NadraVerification" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <resource methods="POST">
        <inSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                <format>
                    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:nad="http://XXXX.Verification" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                        <soapenv:Header/>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                            <nad:GetCitizenDemographics>
                                <nad:franchizeID>XXX</nad:franchizeID>
                                <nad:xml_request_data><![CDATA[
                                <CITIZEN_VERIFICATION><USER_VERIFICATION><USERNAME>XXXX</USERNAME><PASSWORD>XXXX</PASSWORD></USER_VERIFICATION><REQUEST_DATA><TRANSACTION_ID>$4</TRANSACTION_ID><SESSION_ID></SESSION_ID><CITIZEN_NUMBER>$5</CITIZEN_NUMBER><CONTACT_NUMBER>$6</CONTACT_NUMBER><AREA_NAME>$7</AREA_NAME></REQUEST_DATA></CITIZEN_VERIFICATION>
                                ]]></nad:xml_request_data>
                            </nad:GetCitizenDemographics>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                    </soapenv:Envelope>
                </format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.transactionId"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.citizenNo"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.contactNo"/>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.areaName"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <header name="Action" scope="default" value="http://XXXX.XXXX.XXXX/ICitizenVerification/GetCitizenDemographics"/>
            <send>
                <endpoint>
                    <address format="soap11" uri="https://verification.nadra.gov.pk/bioverisys/xml">
                        <suspendOnFailure>
                            <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                            <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                        </suspendOnFailure>
                        <markForSuspension>
                            <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                        </markForSuspension>
                    </address>
                </endpoint>
            </send>
        </inSequence>
        <outSequence>
            <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>&#xd;
{&#xd;
    "status" : "success"&#xd;
    "response": $1
}</format>
                <args>
                    <arg evaluator="json" expression="$.GetCitizenDemographicsResponse.GetCitizenDemographicsResult"/>
                </args>
            </payloadFactory>
            <respond/>
        </outSequence>
        <faultSequence>
            <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>&#xd;
{&#xd;
    "status" : "failure"&#xd;
}</format>
                <args/>
            </payloadFactory>
        </faultSequence>
    </resource>
</api>
```

**Response from External Service after converting XML to JSON**

```json
{
    "GetCitizenDemographicsResponse": {
        "GetCitizenDemographicsResult": "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<CITIZEN_VERIFICATION xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" 
        xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\r\n  <RESPONSE_DATA>\r\n    <RESPONSE_STATUS>\r\n      <CODE>100</CODE>\r\n    
        <MESSAGE>successful</MESSAGE>\r\n    </RESPONSE_STATUS>\r\n    <SESSION_ID>00001343681312</SESSION_ID>\r\n  
        <CITIZEN_NUMBER>XXXX</CITIZEN_NUMBER>\r\n    <PERSON_DATA>\r\n      <NAME>ایوب جمال</NAME>\r\n     
        <FATHER_HUSBAND_NAME>XXX</FATHER_HUSBAND_NAME>\r\n      <PRESENT_ADDRESS>XXXX</PRESENT_ADDRESS>\r\n   
        <PERMANANT_ADDRESS>XXXX</PERMANANT_ADDRESS>\r\n      <DATE_OF_BIRTH>1996-01-10</DATE_OF_BIRTH>\r\n     
        <GENDER>male</GENDER>\r\n      <EXPIRY_DATE>2030-07-11</EXPIRY_DATE>\r\n    </PERSON_DATA>\r\n 
        </RESPONSE_DATA>\r\n</CITIZEN_VERIFICATION>"
    }
}
```

**Actual Response**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body><GetCitizenDemographicsResponse xmlns="http://NADRA.Citizen.Verification"><GetCitizenDemographicsResult>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>&#xd;
&lt;CITIZEN_VERIFICATION xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">&#xd;
  &lt;RESPONSE_DATA>&#xd;
    &lt;RESPONSE_STATUS>&#xd;
      &lt;CODE>107&lt;/CODE>&#xd;
      &lt;MESSAGE>invalid citizen nummber&lt;/MESSAGE>&#xd;
    &lt;/RESPONSE_STATUS>&#xd;
    &lt;SESSION_ID />&#xd;
    &lt;CITIZEN_NUMBER>$5&lt;/CITIZEN_NUMBER>&#xd;
  &lt;/RESPONSE_DATA>&#xd;
&lt;/CITIZEN_VERIFICATION></GetCitizenDemographicsResult></GetCitizenDemographicsResponse></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

**Question**
My exact question is how can I convert the nested xml to json as well?. Since it has converted the first two xml nodes but the third xml node hasn't been converted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using the Payload Factory to modify the response, you can use an XPath expression to extract the values from the soap endpoint. You don't need to explicitly convert the SOAP response to JSON using the `messageType` property before the Payload Factory.

1. Remove the `messageType` property
2. Use an XPath expression in the Payload Factory

**Update Answer**

According to the response from the backend, in the SOAP body, it has declared the `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` tag before the `CITIZEN_VERIFICATION` element. Because of this, we need to first assign it to a property with `OM` type and then use it in the payload factory. Since we have a namespace defined for `GetCitizenDemographicsResponse` we need to add the namespace tag as well to the property mediator.

Option 1: With namespace

```xml
<property type="OM" xmlns:ns="http://NADRA.Citizen.Verification" expression="//ns:GetCitizenDemographicsResponse/*" name="Payload"/>
```

Or you can use `local-name()` function to get the value without defining the namespace in property mediator.

Option 2: Without defining the namespace

```xml
<property type="OM" expression="//*[local-name()='GetCitizenDemographicsResult']" name="Payload"/>
```

```xml
<outSequence>
    <property type="OM" xmlns:ns="http://NADRA.Citizen.Verification" expression="//ns:GetCitizenDemographicsResponse/*" name="Payload"/>
    <payloadFactory media-type="json">
        <format>
        {
            "status" : "success",
            "response": $1
        }
        </format>
        <args>
            <arg expression="$ctx:Payload" />
        </args>
    </payloadFactory>
    <respond/>
</outSequence>
```

Comment: this gives me the API response like this 
{
    "status": "success"
    "response":
}

Comment: if you see the response from the external service it has \r\n as well. Is that causing the issue?

Comment: Can you share the complete response from the external service as well?

Comment: @sonaJ I've updated the Question with the actual response as well

Comment: @sonaJ i need to convert the xml tags to json

Comment: @AyubJamal I have updated the answer. Could you check it now?

Comment: @sonaJ i have checked, now its giving me error: 
ERROR {SequenceMediator} - {api:NadraVerification} com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0] org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxEOFException: Unexpected EOF in prolog
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,0]

Comment: @AyubJamal We need to have the namespace as well in the property mediator. I have updated the answer. Hope this will solve your issue